# Four Directions #6 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, story, knowledge, literature

Inspired by [metazen's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44817/metazen) riddles, I have decided to create my own

> To my west are a bunch of crooks
>
> To my north is a special fruit
>
> To my east is somewhere everyone wants to be
>
> To my south is a giant clock
>
> I am in a collection room

Where am I?

Hint 1:

> Look at the tags

Comment: This is great!  I've had a lot of fun coming up with these.  Glad to see others enjoy the format :)

Answer (score 2):

Just some guesses:

To my west are a bunch of crooks

> This could be reference to City of Thieves, which is a book about Leningrad (St. Petersburg).  Also makes sense with the addition of Story tag to riddle

To my south is a giant clock

> If West is correct, this could be the Kremlin Clock to the south.

Comment: Nice try, but none of these are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are in :

> The British Museum

Based on:

> **To my south is a giant clock** - Big Ben
> **To my west are a bunch of crooks** - HM Prison Wormwood Scrubs

It will be very difficult to fin what you are if the only thing we know is that you are in a collection room. There can be many thing collected there

Comment: Ah, but that is also a hint. You should be able to tell what you are based on where you are. (So it is incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

I am in a collection room

> The maps in the NY Public Library Map Collection Room

To my west are a bunch of crooks

> Wall St.

To my north is a special fruit

> Reference to the Big Apple?

To my east is somewhere everyone wants to be

> Not sure...

To my south is a giant clock

> Clock Tower Building

Comment: You are right about the fruit being some sort of apple, but not the big apple, sorry

Comment: Are all the other parts incorrect as well, then?

Comment: Yep, it is somewhere in a book