# Four Directions #7 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> To the North, take a horse to find something delightful
>   To the West, a game piece that was tight with Paul
>   To the South, he can't smell, although he wasn't spiteful
>   To the East, you might see lavadeserticus crawl
>   
>   Drink and be merry while you admire the floor

### Where and what am I?

---

[Four Directions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/four-directions-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/four-directions-2-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72983/four-directions-3-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/four-directions-4-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73126/four-directions-5-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #6 (by @PotatoLatte)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73177/four-directions-6-where-and-what-am-i)

Comment: Admiring the floor. Interesting clue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are in the

> [House of Dionysus](https://www.cyprusisland.net/attractions/house-dionysus) in Paphos, Cyprus?

To the North, take a horse to find something delightful

> A famed horse, the Byerley Turk, was one of three horses to be forefathers to modern thoroughbred racing. The something delightful is Turkish Delight seems to indicate Turkey is to the North. Per @jafe, the horse refers to the Trojan Horse, and the fabled city of Troy is believed to be in Anatolia. Thanks, @jafe!

To the West, a game piece that was tight with Paul

> A game piece in chess is the Bishop, @Gareth McCaughan found that there's a pun in the word "tight": the Titus to whom one of the allegedly-Pauline letters in the New Testament is addressed was the Bishop of Crete. Thanks, @Gareth! Crete is to the West.

To the South, he can't smell, although he wasn't spiteful

> This could be the Sphinx (since he's missing his nose!) in Egypt, which is to the South.

To the East, you might see lavadeserticus crawl

> This is the Syrian house gecko, endemic to Syria which must be to the East.

Drink and be merry while you admire the floor

> At the entrance of the house is a floor made of shells depicting Scylla. Dionysus is also a God of drinking and being merry in the Greek pantheon.

Comment: Good job! Maybe the horse is a reference to the rot13[gebwna ubefr], though?

Comment: This is correct! Gareth got the reference to the West correct with the tight reference, though you got the game piece reference for the person he mentioned.  The horse reference is still up for grabs, but this is getting the checkmark :)

Comment: Ah!  Yes, @jafe got the last part correct.  This was a quick one, but lots of fun references.

Comment: oh, and rot13(gur fcuvak pna'g fzryy orpnhfr vg'f zvffvat vg'f abfr!).  Clever.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial and doubtful answer**

I suspect you're in

> Cyprus

though I haven't figured everything out.

*To the North, take a horse to find something delightful*

> To the north is Turkey, as in *Turkish delight*. Not quite sure why the horse; there are horses from Turkey and horses in Turkey, but it sounds as if something more specific is intended.

*To the West, a game piece that was tight with Paul*

> Not sure about this. Crete is to the West; perhaps there's a pun in the word "tight" since the Titus to whom one of the allegedly-Pauline letters in the New Testament is addressed was the (a?) leader of the Christian community there -- but I'm not sure why "a game piece".

*To the South, he can't smell, although he wasn't spiteful*

> To the south is Egypt. Many Egyptian statues have had their noses removed (though presumably not "cut off to spite their faces"), for reasons that aren't perfectly clear.

*To the East, you might see lavadeserticus crawl*

> To the east is Syria; *Hemidactylus lavedeserticus* is the Syrian house gecko.

*Drink and be merry while you admire the floor*

> Not sure quite what's going on there. There are some fine mosaics on Cyprus, I guess, but again it seems like there's more to it than that.

Comment: Great answer! I like your explanations as well! :D

Comment: Yours is better (now that it's moved to the same island as mine :-) ).

Comment: Your island was definitely better, once I solved the south clue I figured my previous answer was off the mark! (+1) from me, Gareth!

Comment: Nice work, you were right on.  +1 from me.