# Four Directions #8 - Where and what am I? (fan-made)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> To the north is a bank of extreme altercations.
>   To the west is a land that is claimed by no nations.
>   To the south is a seat of a union's operations.
>   To the east is a site of devout lapidations.
>   Five years since they laid down this giant's foundations.

What and where am I?

---

Earlier parts in the series:
[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900),
[#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914),
[#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72983),
[#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73065),
[#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73126),
[#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73177),
[#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73209)

Comment: Inspired by the series started by @MetaZen.

Comment: Nice!  Great rhyming :)

Comment: Love these riddles! I'm going to make one sometime soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are the

> Jeddah Tower in Jeddah, Saudi Arabia.

To the north is a bank of extreme altercations.

> This could be the West Bank in Israel/Palestine

To the west is a land that is claimed by no nations.

> As @Duck mentioned, the Bir Tawil Triangle

To the south is a seat of a union's operations.

> The African Union is seated in Addis Ababa, Ethiopia

To the east is a site of devout lapidations.

> In Mecca, they have a Stoning of the Devil ceremony (devout lapidation means religious stoning)

Five years since they laid down this giant's foundations.

> Construction on the Jeddah Tower started in 2013, 5 years ago.

Comment: I was thinking hey, yeah Mecca would work, but then I thought since it was over water that it couldn't be right lol +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @Duck! I think that the actual answer is also over the water as well....fingers crossed!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure, but I think yours is right!

Comment: Yup, this is it! Everything's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but:

> The hala'ib triangle in Egypt?

To the west is a land that is claimed by no nations.

> The Bir Tawil Triangle?

To the north is a bank of extreme altercations.

> 

To the south is a seat of a union's operations.

> Port of Sudan?

To the east is a site of devout lapidations.

> 

Five years since they laid down this giant's foundations.

> The pyramids?