# Four Directions #9 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> To the North is a fortress containing a rose.
>   To the West is a place that may leave you aghast. 
>   To the South stay on track to see where it goes.
>   To the East is a place you won't find in the past.
>   
>   My buddy and I welcome you.

Where and what am I?

Hint #1: (pasting here for visibility):

> At least three of the clues are plays on words.

Hint #2:

> Borealis missing from what's to the North

Hint #3:

> You could be at all five places in less than an hour, though definitely not through them all!

---

Earlier parts in the series:
[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900),
[#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914),
[#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72983),
[#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73065),
[#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73126),
[#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73177),
[#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73209),
[#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73259)

Comment: Hint #1:  rot13(Ng yrnfg guerr bs gur pyhrf ner n cynl ba jbeqf.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all locations within the

> Disneyland amusement park in Anaheim

To the North is a fortress containing a rose.

> Sleeping Beauty Castle, home of Princess Aurora aka Briar Rose

To the West is a place that may leave you aghast.

> Haunted Mansion Holiday

To the South stay on track to see where it goes.

> Disneyland Railroad

To the East is a place you won't find in the past.

> Tomorrowland

My buddy and I welcome you.

> The statue of Walt Disney and Mickey Mouse at the centre of the park.

Comment: That's it!  Nice work!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You are in (partial and working on answer)

> Croatia

North

> Fortress Medvedgrad, which contains Rose Windows

West:

> Working on this one

South:

> One of the rails, working out which one

East:

> Serbia, which is East of Zagreb, didn't exist in the past. It was founded in 2006.

I'm thinking the what is:

> The Zagreb Cathedral, the tallest Cathedral in Croatia, which also has two steeples (my buddy and I)

Comment: This is not correct, but I like the matches to the clues.  In particular, the clue for South is the right idea.

Comment: @MetaZen dang okay. Time to think deeper

Comment: @MetaZen I have updated my answer

Comment: Still not the place.  Your original South answer was along the right track (so to speak) as far as the idea, though not the location.  I will add a hint that may be helpful

Comment: @MetaZen Man.. okay. I figured they were your clue, going to keep thinking. Thanks!

Comment: @MetaZen Not sure if you want to answer but rot13(Qbrf vg unir nalguvat gb qb jvgu gur Haqretebhaq Envyebnq va gur HF?)

Comment: It doesn't have to do with that one, but the South clue does have to do with a different one in the same country

Comment: @MetaZen rot13(Vf vg Arhfpujnafgrva Pnfgyr gb gur Abegu? V xrcg ybbxvat va Pebngvn sebz bar bs lbhe bgure pbzzragf, ohg guvf frrzf gb svg.)

Comment: It was not - @jafe found the correct answer.  Thanks for working on it!