# Four Directions #10 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, geography

> To the North the royals doth lie, watching the sun cross the sky.
>
> To the South they stand in a line, and a dance they will call mine.
>
> To the West the sea doth crash, against the white worth a lot of cash.
>
> To the East is where in modern day, the pirates leave and have their say.
>
> And there I stand, in the middle of it all. And I am, by no means small.

Previous [Four Directions #9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73339/four-directions-9-where-and-what-am-i)

Comment: Awesome - another good one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see...

To the North the royals doth lie, watching the sun cross the sky.

> Egyptian pharaohs in their tombs

To the South they stand in a line, and a dance they will call mine.

> Conga lines being danced in Congo

To the West the sea doth crash, against the white worth a lot of cash.

> Ivory Coast

To the East is where in modern day, the pirates leave and have their say.

> Somalia and its notorious pirates

And there I stand, in the middle of it all. And I am, by no means small.

> Central African Republic?

Comment: Nice one, you got it!