# Four Directions #11 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, geography

> To the North: Is a place where conflict has yet to die
>
> To the East: Is a place where the dead can be a marker
>
> To the West: Is a place where its Fort and its pass is Key
>
> To the South: Is a place for a pearl
>
> And there I lie with a stone of black among the tranquil gardens

Hint:

> To the west: My key is to a plateau

Hint 2:

> Here is where the fire consumed me to ash

Previous: [Four Directions #10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73365/four-directions-10-where-and-what-am-i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got it ! I know I'm late to the party... Still :

I agree with @Jafe, @Flying_whale and @AHKieran, see their answers for the Four Directions solutions.

I think you are

> Mahatma Gandhi, resting in the [Raj Ghat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raj_Ghat_and_associated_memorials) where a black marble platform marks the spot of Mahatma Gandhi's cremation.

This is my first time answering here, but here's hoping to start something great !

Comment: That is correct :)

Answer (score 5):

Utilising @Jafe and @Flying_whale 's partial answers

*To the North: Is a place where conflict has yet to die*

> Kashmir, disputed between India, Pakistan and China

*To the East: Is a place where the dead can be a marker*

> Mount Everest.

*To the West: Is a place where its Fort and its pass is Key*

> From @Dewey823 "Azirgarh Fort, Pass to the Deccan Plateau." <s>Bolan Pass in Western Pakistan was once one of the major gateways from Central Asia to South Asia.</s>

*To the South: Is a place for a pearl*

> Hyderabad, centre of India's pearl industry

*And there I lie with a stone of black among the tranquil gardens*

> Using the other points to triangulate, I think this refers to New Dheli, where there are lots of tranquil gardens.

Comment: So close, the west is incorrect. I'm adding a hint for West. You are on the right track in New Delhi :)

Answer (score 4):

partial answer

to the east

> Mt Everest. there's a dead body (can't remember how we call it) that tells people they're almost at the top.

to the north, maybe

> Tibet, it's not still quiet between China and Tibet

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. I like your dead sea thinking though, but might be hard to use the dead as a marker :)

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker changed my east, I think it's more relevant now :)

Comment: rot13(Lbh vaqrrq unir Rnfg pbeerpg!)

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker did it for north too, will try to find the other 2 :p

Comment: North is wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer for the West Clue

> Azirgarh Fort, Pass to the Deccan Plateau. 
>  "In the 16th century, Asirgarh was regarded as the strongest fort ever built; its reputation further attested by travelers from across the world who had not seen a fortress so strong which had enough provisions and ammunition to withstand a long siege. Asirgarh was the coveted ‘Key to Deccan’ and the Faruqis were not going to hand over the key yet. Not even to the Mughal Emperor Akbar."

Comment: Indeed, nice job :)

Comment: Cool, whoever feels like they did the most work can grab it

Answer (score 2):

### Partial Answer

To the North is:

> North and South Korea

To the East is:

> 

To the West is:

> Jiayu Pass perhaps?

To the South is:

> 

And there I lie with a stone of black among the tranquil gardens:

> You may be in Kyoto to be honest; there are plenty Zen gardens here and some of which feature black stone center pieces.

Comment: I like your answers, but this is not it :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial, working from @CodeLikeBeaker's answer:

For West:

> Khyber Fort and Khyber Pass is one of the most important passes in the area, making it "key".

Comment: rot13(Evtug nern, jnl zber gb gur abegu)

Answer (score 2):

Partial

To the North: Is a place where conflict has yet to die

> Kashmir, disputed between India, Pakistan and China

To the East: Is a place where the dead can be a marker

> Mount Everest, as Flying_whale found out

To the West: Is a place where its Fort and its pass is Key

> ?

To the South: Is a place for a pearl

> Hyderabad, centre of India's pearl industry

And there I lie with a stone of black among the tranquil gardens

> ?

Comment: Right on track!