# Four Directions #12 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> To the South is the jewel in the ring you can't wear
>
> To the East was envisioned a mountain pair
>
> To the North climb a tree to work your own way
>
> To the West are buildings that don't see the light of day
>
> I create dearly beloved untruths

**Hint 1**

> Untruth that I make is real and nice.
>  Why call it untruth? Because it's a lie!

**Hint 2**

> I'm closer to North than South or East.
>  You'll want to stop by if you yearn for a feast.

**Hint 3**

> There are memes, there are things that inspired memes, and there are things that inspired the things that inspired memes.

Previous: [Four Directions #11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73393/four-directions-11-where-and-what-am-i)

Comment: Just saw this was never solved.  Can we get a new clue?  Hint #1 makes me think of maybe a r13(jrqqvat puncry) but that may just be me being cynical :)

Comment: @MetaZen It gets harder to come up with clues that don't just give the answer away... But at least I still remember the answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have already found the locations north, south, east and west. The place we are looking for is

> [the Regent Bakery and Cafe](http://www.regentbakeryandcafe.com/redmond) in Seattle

because

> to quote from the page linked above, "our black forest cake became an illustration in the video game Portal as a "reward cake" due to a local game developers' fondness for the cake". The cake is a dearly beloved untruth because ["the cake is a lie"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-cake-is-a-lie).

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

South:

> I'm thinking it has to do with Petrified wood (rings in the wood), which is the jewel of the state of Washington. Thinking Mt Saint Helens as it's part of the ring of fire.

East:

> Snoqualmie, WA. Where Twin Peaks was filmed.

North

> Is this referring to the Microsoft Treehouse? These offices are where employees can work

West

> The Seattle Underground. These buildings were built on top of due to the fire in 1889. They will never see the light of day again.

What Am I?

> Working on..hmmm

Comment: Correct for North, incorrect for South.

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova still working on the what, but I might have the rest

Comment: The partials are correct (rot13(V jnf guvaxvat Zbhag Envavre vafgrnq bs Zbhag Uryra nf vg'f pybfre, ohg Zbhag Uryra jvyy nyfb qb)). Now for the final answer...

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova rot13(V unir n srryvat vg'f n cynl ba jbeqf, naq dhvgr cbffvoyl n zbivr ersrerapr?)

Comment: Sort of, but not exactly...

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova okay, took a gander at what it might be

Comment: No. rot13(Ovt Snxr Jrqqvat) is not specific to the area, and the right answer is.

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova rot13(Enaqbz thrff urer, ohg Juvgr Evire Nzcuvgurngre? Fvapr gurl gryy fgbevrf (yvrf), naq fgbevrf ner perngrq gurer? Uneq gb svaq fghss jvgu gur Fbhgu pyhr fb sne sebz gur erfg)

Comment: No. You were on to something rot13(zbivr ersrerapr) guess, though it's not rot13(zbivr) :-)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova rot13(V'z guvaxvat vg zvtug or "Oevqyr Genvyf Fgngr Cnex" ohg V'z abg fher ubj gung jbhyq or eryngrq gb n "abg" zbivr, be yvrf yby. V'z fher V'z bire guvaxvat guvf..), but maybe not due to location.. sigh

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really fit any clues about the place (not the rot13(srnfg) either).

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> Could the mountain pair be referring to The Pitons on St Lucia?

Comment: No (although I admit they are pretty)